# multipolygon: switch coordinate arrays with javascript/jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, array

I have a geojson with multiple arrays, such as:

```
[[10.77932197941255,52.03584196145097],[10.77932197941255,52.03575906909681],[10.779636389761993,52.03575906909681],[10.779636389761993,52.03584196145097],[10.77932197941255,52.03584196145097]]
```

I need to write some code, which iterates each array and switches both elements in each sub-array (are these called like that?)

The result should look like this:

> ```
> [[52.03584196145097,10.77932197941255],[52.03575906909681,10.77932197941255,],[52.03575906909681,10.779636389761993],[52.03584196145097,10.779636389761993],[52.03584196145097,10.77932197941255]]
> ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var oldArray = [[10.77932197941255,52.03584196145097],
[10.77932197941255,52.03575906909681],
[10.779636389761993,52.03575906909681],
[10.779636389761993,52.03584196145097],
[10.77932197941255,52.03584196145097]];

var newArray = [];

for (var i = 0; i < oldArray.length; i++) {

  var oldCoordinate = oldArray[i];
  var newCoordinate = [oldCoordinate[1], oldCoordinate[0]];

  newArray.push(newCoordinate);

}
```

"newArray" now has all the switched coordinates.
See the fiddle here for testing: [jsfiddle.net/8rLhj0o3/](https://jsfiddle.net/8rLhj0o3/)

Comment: another question: lets say i have a multipolygon and I want to iterate through all polygons like in your answer. when i try this, I only get one huge array with connected geometries. how would i do loop this correctly?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/dr0m62yn/1/

Comment: You need to run multiple for loops inside each other, depending on the data. See this fiddle with a working example: https://jsfiddle.net/xyg2Le47/